# JButton or JLabel drag and drop

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel

I've got a little problem.

I need to get an Drag & drop event on a JLabel or JButton throug a JPanel.
I explain, I've got a JPanel on my app, and I want to put a JLabel or JButton on it, and when I drag it, it moves arround the panel to finally get the bounds (I know how to do this) to save it on a BBDD.  It's like the Icons on a desktop from any OS

Anyone knows how i can do this?

Thanks to all
Best regards Carlos